# Google Analytics with Ionic

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, google-play, ionic-framework

I am trying to add Google Analytics into an Ionic/ phonegap/ Covdova app using  [this](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-google-analytics-ionicframework/). However, I am getting these errors:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-service
>   s-analytics:+.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ana
>   lytics/maven-metadata.xml
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ana
>   lytics/
>        Required by:
>            :android:unspecified

I have Android SDK and Google Play service installed. I even try to use the older version it mentioned in the document: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics@0.7.1` but that gives the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the answer in [this comment](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/123#issuecomment-121426281).

Running `android` and then installing/updating

- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library
- Google Play Services
- Google Repository

fixed the problem for me.

It sounds like several people also had to change the plugin version

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics@0.7.1
```

but I didn't have to do this.

Comment: I like to add I have tried updating the four items above but didn't work, then I realise there were some incompatible files left behind when I switch to cordova-plugin-google-analytics@0.7.1 and back to the latest. If I create a fresh project, with the latest Android dependencies, the ionic project builds fine, with the latest version of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

try removing platform and add it again,

```
ionic platform rm android

ionic platform add android
```

this trick worked for me.